# Can you change the order in which RenderSection executes?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

Is there a way to tell the RenderSection to run *after* everything else on the _layout page is completed?

I have a RenderSection which contains Javascript. I want to modify elements on the _Layout.cshtml page.
If the RenderSection is called after the element on the _Layout page then it works fine but if RenderSection is called before the end it doesn't work since the element in the _Layout does not yet exist.

```
        <h1 id="AA"> NewContent </h1>      <!-- works because AA exists -->

        @RenderSection("MySection")        <!-- Contains javascript to add New Content to AA and BB -->

        <h1 id="BB"> </h1>                 <!-- Does not receive content because it does not exist yet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way of changing the order that Razor renders sections but I found a work around.

There's a tutorial on W3Schools which allows you to insert HTML from a URL into a DIV of your choice.

[How to insert HTML tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

This allows you to specify a URL in your DIV from where to load the HTML. In my case, I just loaded it from one of my MVC controllers.

```
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>
```

You can then just call a method when you are ready to load your HTML in.

```
includeHTML();
```